# Ionic5 row - reduce height

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

The default height of my `ion-row` is too much. See screenshot. It only contains an icon. I would like to restrict it to the minimum width possible. How? I tried it with `no-margin` but didn't work.

Below is the code

[image]

```
<ion-grid *ngIf="!drawerIsIdle()" class="ion-no-margin">
    <ion-row class="ion-no-margin">
      <ion-col size='5' class="ion-no-margin"></ion-col>
      <ion-col size='2' class="ion-no-margin">
        <ion-button fill="clear" size="small" (click)="hideDrawer()">
          <ion-icon name="remove-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size='5' class="ion-no-margin"></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-grid *ngIf="drawerIsIdle()">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="4" text-center><ion-button color="10-session" fill="clear" size="small">Hi</ion-button></ion-col>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to remove some padding using `class="ion-no-padding"`.

Inspect your(s) element(s) in the browser to check padding.

Chrome(in example)

[image: chrome inspector]

Comment: Hmmm, the ionic styling is bit more complex than regular css

Comment: I know... there a ionic class "ion-no-padding" you can use.

Comment: By the way, to simplify your code, you can also use 'offset' in your col definition instead of adding empty col before and after your button col.

Comment: Thanks, `class="ion-no-padding"` seems to work. Add it to the answer and I'll send you some karma. :D

Comment: class added in answer! Thanks for karma ;-)